# Load byte value from a DB variable into 16-bit register (sign or zero extend a byte)

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, dos, dosbox

I m using MASM compilor and DOSBOX. I want to want to save value from a variable into register. I want to save `num1` value into `cx` register. How can I do that?

```
      .MODEL SMALL
.STACK  50H
.DATA
num1 db '5'
    NL  DB  0DH, 0AH, '$'        
    msg     db ?,0AH,0DH,"Enter an odd number between 0 to 10:$"
     nxtline db 0Ah,0DH,"$"
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    
    
            
              LEA DX,msg     
              mov ah,9
              int 21H
              LEA DX,nxtline    
              mov ah,9
              int 21H
              
              MOV AH,1                    
              INT 21H 
              LEA DX,nxtline    
              mov ah,9
              int 21H
              
              
              
       mov bl,al   ;save the value from input
              mov num1,bl
               LEA DX,num1     
              mov ah,9
              int 21H
              mov cl,al 
              
   main endp
   end main
```

Comment: want to take input and assign that value to CX register

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: YEs i just want to take value from user which is in mov bl,al  Now i want to asign that value to CX register how can i do that ?

Comment: Yes m getting @ joze through  MOV AH,1  INT 21H

Comment: after that m getting input value into bl  through mov bl,al. Now i want to assign that value to CX register how can i do that@ joze

Comment: @anila - use xor cx,cx | mov cl,al . If you want a number, you probably want to use sub al,030h to convert Ascii '0' to '9' to values 0 to 9.

Comment: Yes i want to assign number value to a cx register How can i do that i did that what u said but didnt get the results

Comment: Anila, do as @rcgldr told you.

Comment: Just a minut @ joze m editing my code now u can see

Comment: @ joze now tel me how can i do that

Comment: More generally, if `AL` contains a *signed* number then you could use `CBW; MOV CX,AX`.

Comment: @rcgldr after getting value using this xor cx,cx | mov cl,al still dont assign it

Comment: where the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are losing the value entered by the user in `AL`. You input one char with this:

```
          MOV AH,1                    
          INT 21H
```

The char is stored in `AL`, but before you save the value in `BL` you display a line break:

```
          LEA DX,nxtline    
          mov ah,9
          int 21H
```

And the value in `AL` is gone because this interrupt uses `AL` to display a string. The solution is to save the value in `BL` **before** you display the line break:

```
          MOV AH,1                    
          INT 21H 
   mov bl,al   ;save the value from input
          LEA DX,nxtline    
          mov ah,9
          int 21H
```

**Edit :** move value into `CX` :

```
xor cx,cx       ;CLEAR CX.
mov cl,bl       ;MOVE CHAR INTO CL.
sub cl, 48      ;CONVERT CHAR TO DIGIT, EXAMPLE: '5' -> 5.
```

Comment: @joze how can i fix this let me know ? I just want to take a value from user and save that in cx register which is a number.

Comment: @ joze in num1 variable value is stored i just want to mov that value to a cx register how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

BTW: that source you posted, can't be compiled (`num1` not defined).

In general to load value from memory into register you can use:

```
mov reg8|16|32|64,[<memory_address>]
```

Example:

```
num1: db 7
```

Assembler will compile this into single byte containing value `7`, and it will take a note into symbol table, that label `num1` exists, pointing at that byte.

```
num2: dw 0x0809
```

This will be compiled as two bytes: `09 08` (least significant part of number goes first into memory, so `09` is at `num2` address, `08` is at `num2+1` address). The `num2` label is put into symbol table, pointing at the first byte of the defined word (value `09`).

```
mov bl,[num1]   ; loads value 7 into bl
mov cx,[num2]   ; loads value 0x0809 (8*256+9 = 2057 in decimal) into cx
mov al,[num2]   ; loads value 9 into al
mov ah,[num2+1] ; loads value 8 into ah = now ax contains 2057. (ax = ah:al)
mov dx,[num1]   ; will load dl with 7, and dh with something what is after it
  ; if you wanted "num1", then this is bug, as "num1" is only 1 byte "wide"
  ; and dx is 16 bit register, so it's two bytes wide.
```

To load 8 bit value from `bl` into 16 bit register `cx` you have several options, but all follow the same principle, you have to extend the 8 bit value to be 16 bit "wide".

```
mov cl,bl   ; set's lower 8 bits of cx to bl, doesn't care about upper 8 bits
  ; ^ unless done on purpose, this is bug, as "cx" has unexpected value

movzx cx,bl ; "zx" = zero-extend, value 0xFE (254) will become 0x00FE (254)
  ; recommended way for 386+ code (does not exist on 8086-80286 CPUs)

movsx cx,bl ; "sx" = sign-extend, so value 0xFE (-2) will become 0xFFFE (-2)
  ; recommended way for 386+ code (does not exist on 8086-80286 CPUs)

xor cx,cx   ; cx = 0
mov cl,bl   ; same as first example, but ch was set to zero with previous ins.
  ; recommended way for 8086 code

mov ch,bl  ; ch = bl, cl undefined
sar cx,8   ; cx = sign extended bl to 16 bits (bl=0xFE will set cx=0xFFFE)
  ; "recommended" way for 8086 code (not really, but who cares about 8086 anyway)
  ; for al -> ax sign extension there's specialized CBW instruction


mov cl,bl      ; cl = bl, ch undefined
and cx,0x00FF  ; AND with 0x00FF will clear ch, and keep cl
  ; not recommended (slower), just example that any valid math works of course
```

To verify these works, **launch the code in debugger**, and watch the values of register to change after stepping over each instruction.

---

Your updated question is "how to display number in x86 assembler".

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info , search for "How do I handle multi-digit numbers?"

But at first you should probably also search what is ASCII, and how "strings" in computer work, and how they differ from numeric values in register.

On most of the platforms (DOS too) you can't just do `mov cx,1234` and print that on screen with single instruction as string "1234". You have to first build an ASCII string containing five characters `1234$` in some memory buffer (from the 16b numeric value in `cx`), then you can use `int 21h,9` to display that string.

Comment: @anila That will compile as single byte with value `0x35` (hexa) == `53` in decimal == `0011 0101` binary == ASCII code for digit character `'5'`. Whether it is correct? Depends if you want value 53 in that byte. It's not number. `'5' + '5' = 'j'`! Because 53+53 = 106, and 106 is ASCII code for `'j'`. You should have clear idea, what values you want to calculate. If you want to calculate ASCII strings, `'5'` is probably what you want. If you want numbers, you want `5`. If you want to display numbers as ASCII string, you have to write a code which will convert number into string (`printf` in C)

Comment: @anila mind you, from your questions you look so confused, that if I would be on your place, I would stop printing anything to screen, and just play with debugger to see values in register, and learn few instructions first like that, manipulating numbers, and watching it in debugger. Then do some memory manipulations small tasks, like setting 10 bytes of memory to zero, etc.... After that take a look how "hello world" example is done, how the "string" is encoded in computer memory, and what is ASCII. After that take a look on that number-to-string formatting function from x86/info link.

Comment: @anila you can literally watch in your browser, how simpler fictional 8 bit machine works with hello world example: http://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/  ... push "assembly" and see how memory is filled with compiled code. then "step" over it, and highlight `C` and `D` registers, note how text is displayed on top text display, when it is written into end of memory (video ram). That's similar how VGA text modes worked in DOS, and like what `int 21h,9` is doing (before the text mode video ram is emulated by graphic pixel by dosbox in your real OS).